# Oracle PL/SQL : to_date() format not considered

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, format

When I execute this in PL/SQL Developer :

```
SELECT to_date('29/03/17 14:05','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI')  FROM dual;
```

Here's what I get :

```
3/29/2017 2:05:00 PM
```

How is this possible ? I use `HH24` but it seems like it's `HH` that's being used instead. The day and month are also not in the format I entered.

Comment: you have `pm` then it's good

Comment: Dates don't really have a format when stored, only when displayed. This is more about display settings, or your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, than anything else

Comment: as an aside, why are you still using two-digit years? Years have four digits! Why make the database guess as to whether you mean 2017 or 1917 or even 2117 when you can be specific?!

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing with the `to_date` method is parsing the string into a date object. If you then want to output the date object as string with a different format you should use the `to_char` method.

Example:

```
SELECT to_char(
    to_date('29/03/17 14:05','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI'), 
    'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI'
) FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, conceptual excercise coming up

Which of these dates represents the 1st January 2017?

```
01/01/2017
2017-01-01
01-JAN-2017
```

That's right, all of them. The date datatype is not a format, it stores the value of the date, not how it appears.

If using Oracle, adjust your NLS_DATE_FORMAT to match your expectation, but again, this is just how the system will *display* the date, not how it stores it.

Answer (score 1):

(N.B. This answer is more to give more clarity to the other answers but it's too long for a comment.)

Oracle stores DATEs (and TIMESTAMPs etc) in its own specific format. Us humans represent dates in a variety of different formats and we deal with strings. Even us humans can get confused over what a date string represents, given no context - e.g. `03/09/2017` - is that the 3rd of September, 2017 or the 9th of March 2017?

So, when you pass a date into Oracle, you need to convert it into Oracle's date format by passing a string in and telling Oracle what the date format of that string is. This can be done using `to_date()` or via the `DATE` literal (which is always in `yyyy-mm-dd` format).

Conversely, when you want to read something that's stored in Oracle's DATE datatype, you need to tell Oracle how you want it to be displayed, which you can do by using `to_char()` with the appropriate format mask.

If you fail to explicitly convert the string-to-a-date or date-to-a-string, then Oracle uses the format specified in the NLS_DATE_FORMAT to decide how to do the conversion.

In your case, you didn't specify how you wanted your date to be displayed, so Oracle has to use `to_char()` along with the format contained in your NLS_DATE_FORMAT in order to display the date as a string, and clearly that's different to the format you passed the date-string in as.